# HTML5 Audio not playing after src URL injected in

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html, audio

I have something like this on page load:

```
echo "<td class='audio'><audio controls><source src></audio></td>";
```

I then make an ajax call based on click to pull relative audio URL's from an API I'm working with to be used as the src.

Upon visiting one of those audio URL's in a separate tab, the audio **does** in fact play. My thinking is that it's not playing where I need it to because it doesn't get a source until it needs it (used ajax to cut down on load time due to rather large API calls).

Any thoughts?

Comment: can you elaborate an example of your issue? https://jsfiddle.net/4ubfnjts/

Comment: @DaniP I have an array of audio URLs being grabbed from the API, for every one of those URL's, an HTML5 audio object is generated, but the source is left blank until the user clicks on the area relative to the accordion I have with all of this information. I have a loop set up to set the URLs as the src for each of one of these audio objects. Even upon inspection and testing of the URL, everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your `source` tag is missing the filetype information. Even is `src` is replaced by `src="your_path/your_file.mp3"`, it also needs for example `type="audio/mpeg"` for an mp3-file. The full generated HTML code would have to be something like

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="your_path/your_file.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Comment: Really thought that was going to be the solution, but still won't work! I've tried so many different things now, this seems so simple.

Comment: If you look at the generated page/audio div (in the browsers developer tools), what is the exact source code?

Answer (score 0):

This is work me,or may be you can remove the `<source src="">` tag and add `src=""` inside of the `<audio>` tag

https://shty.ml?j2n7MxkhKm
When you enter this link then click the `Preview` button